# Determining whether Newton-Raphon's method will converge linearly or quadraticaly

Tags: numerical-methods, newton-raphson

So lets say you have the following two polynomials:

$$f_1(x)=(x-1)(x-2)^2$$

and

$$f_2(x)=(x-1)^2(x-2)$$

And we want know whether Newton-Raphon's method will converge quadraticly or linearly for finding the root $x=2$. How would I go by doing this?

Comment: You could conduct numerical experiments (if that is allowed in your course and you have access to computational tools which makes it attractive to do).

Comment: I do know how you can perform the newton raphson method and see how the error changes after testing some starting point. However I was thinking there is some other easier and less time consuming way to check this since the solution to this problem states that $f_1(x)$ is linear because 2 is a double root and $f_2(x)$ is quadratic because 2 is a simple root, which I don't understand.

Comment: I don't remember all the details of Newton Rhapsons method, I mostly remember the practical methods to find stuff out, but if you are reading it as part of a course maybe they want a theoretical explanation instead of a practical method. Maybe you can ask your professor what approach would be acceptable.